# Oracle- show all name columns (more then 30 characters) is possible?

Tags: oracle

Hy, can you help me whith this? I want to show the entire name of the columns(from the pivot). Ca this be possible? I know that tha maximum lenght is 30...

Comment: Please, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to build a query with a column alias longer than 30 characters; if so, you only can in [Oracle 12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/exadata-express-cloud/csdbf/longer-identifier-names.html#GUID-F4CA155F-5A37-4705-8443-0A8C9E3F875C) and on.

With previous versions, this is what you get:

```
SQL> select 1 as "Alias with 30 characters -----"
  2  from dual;

Alias with 30 characters -----
------------------------------
                             1

SQL> select 1 as "Alias with 31 characters -----X"
  2  from dual;
select 1 as "Alias with 31 characters -----X"
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```